# How to create a docker cluster with MQ without Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, dockerfile, kubectl, kubelet

How to create a docker  cluster with  MQ without Kubernetes ?  or with kubernetes is also fine , but has any one configured this before ? if so can you please help me out ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to fabric8 MQ I understand from their website that they *only* run kubernetes based. And from what I understand it's a packaged platform that used Docker, Jenkins, Kubernetes for easier Microservices development.

I haven't done the setup myself yet, but I assume their [quickstart](https://fabric8.io/guide/quickstarts/walkthrough.html) may be a good starting point.

Comment: I was referring too IBM MQ